# pass a bool expression as a method parameter

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, func

i am a bit confused trying to implement a more elegant generic solution using `lambda`/`LINQ` `Expression` or `Func<bool>` to simply replace a `bool` return type.

say the expression is:

```
public bool someBoolRetMethod(someType parA, someOtherType parB) {
    if(parA==null)
        return new ExpM("relevant msg").Rtrn;
}
```

so now if `parA` is `null`, `ExpM()` is a class that deals with errors

what i wanted to do is pass the condition as a parameter :

```
public class ExpBoolCond:ExpM {

    public bool Rtrn{get;set;}
    public ExpBoolCond(theBool, themsg) {
        variable to hold theBool;
        if(theBool) new specialMbxWindow(themsg)
        then set Rtrn..
    }
}
```

so in that way i could use:

```
 var condNullParA = new ExpBoolCond(parA==null, "passed ParA is Null,\r\nAborting method <sub>(methodName and line# is handled inside  ExpM base class)</sub> !")
if(condNullParA.Rtrn) ....
```

what is the correct way to implement it ?

Update :

```
 public class ExcBCondM:ExcpM
 {
     public bool Rtrn { get { return this._Rtrn(); } }
     Func<bool> _Rtrn { get; set; }
     public ExcBCondM(Func<bool> cond, string bsMsg)
        : base(bsMsg,false)
     {
        this._Rtrn = cond;
        //if (this._Rtrn) this.show();
     }
     public bool activateNon() { this.show(); return false; }
 }
```

usage:

```
public bool someBoolRetMethod(some_passed_Type parA)
{
    var someCondExpM =  new ExpBoolCond(() => parA==null, "relevant Message");
    if(someCondExpM.Rtrn) 
    return someCondExpM.activateNon(); //if() now Calls Func<bool> _Rtrn  when called rather where stated.
  return true;//if ok...
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear exactly what you're trying to do in the first place. What's wrong with the simple code you've already got? (It would also help if you'd use a full concrete example with idiomatic names....)

Comment: Your question is rather chaotic, please reread it and rewrite it. Currently it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JonSkeet i just want to pass "the simple"  `parA==null` condition  as parameter and don't know how. the why is not really clear to me if it is efficient but i learn lambda / LINQ that way ...

Comment: Why do you need a lambda expression at all though? Why not just make the parameter of type `bool`? And you really, really need to know *why* you're trying to do something - what you're trying to achieve. You shouldn't be trying to use lambda expressions and LINQ just for the sake of it.

Comment: @JbobJohan: If that's what the OP is trying to achieve, they need to make that a *lot* clearer... along with a more realistic scenario in which it's important. I'm still struggling to see a real purpose at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet its cause I see a point where the condition should be first stated and asked about only later in the code that is why I want to say : here is a condition . don't eval now just keep in mind till I ask for the value (Rtrn)

Comment: @Robb_2015: Um, that's what Jbob Johan just wrote in another comment, then deleted. Are you by any chance one user on two accounts? (And my reply stands: your question doesn't have any of that in it at the moment.)

Comment: The only sensible way of doing this is `if (parA == null) { /* do whatever you need to do */ }` or maybe `try { if (parA == null) { throw new Exception (); } /* ...*/ } catch (Exception e) { ... }`.

Comment: @JonSkeet ,sorry i am in another workstation of my colleague  now had to log out, i will take care of a clear / realistic example reEdit shortly, thanks !

Comment: @JohnB  i am implementing a workaround for Exeption as it is expensive , why lazy ? i need to evaluate few things , this one is just an example, the answer time is importent  should not evaluated on the spot , as it sometimes needed to be checked on the point it is relevant

Comment: @JonSkeet i hope you can see why it needed to be evaluated not on the spot but only when asked to evaluate given condition

Comment: That still does not make much sense to me.

Comment: No, it's still not clear - particularly as you use cryptic names such as "ExcBCondM" which is completely meaningless, and other names which aren't even conventional (using underscores, and with type names and method names not starting with capital letters). This question is still really unclear IMO.

Comment: And as for working around exceptions - I've found that 99% of the time, that's a bad idea. Exceptions should only occur in exceptional situations, at which point the performance penalty isn't a problem. You're making your life way more complicated for no obvious real benefit.

Comment: @JonSkeet Exc is `Exception` prefix BCond is better than BC  bool Condition. M postfix is for model , i have huge Type  namespace, which is bunch of models alternative to .Net... one day  i will send you a link to a code review of a complete debug app manager-project-genrator and ORM all together.. that helps on every new project i create.

Comment: How was anyone meant to make any sense of that? Questions should be written to be understandable without knowing your hidden (and IMO still undesirable) naming convention. The whole question is still unclear IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create `Func<bool>` as a lambda expression, the syntax is as follows:

```
var condNullParA = new ExpBoolCond(() => parA==null, "passed ParA is Null,\r\nAborting method <sub>(methodName and line# is handled inside  ExpM base class)</sub> !")
//                                 ^^^^^
```

The `() =>` part tells C# compiler that the expression that follows should become a body of a lambda that takes no parameters, and returns whatever is the type of the expression to the right of the `=>` sign, i.e. a `bool`.

Comment: and that way the parA=null will be evaluated only when I call `condNullParA.Rtrn` rather than on the spot...?

Comment: Why should you want to evaluate such a simple condition lazily (i.e. not immediately)?

Comment: @JbobJohan The condition would be evaluated only when `theBool` is evaluated, which requires a call, i.e. `if(theBool())` (note the pair of parentheses).

Comment: so `Func<Bool>` is the type parameter representing the "parA==null" statment of the if()?  ==> `public ExpBoolCond( Func<bool> theBool, string themsg)`

Comment: thanks alot . that's the correct answer then, the only thing is the `() =>` is a bit annoying there  but i guess in any other-way will need to declare a var Func bool which is even more syntax